# How to style a div underneath another div in a fluid layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a somewhat complex HTML/css combination that I want to achieve. I can have any number of divs in a row and each of them will have some information pertaining to that div. The divs are represented as the red boxes in my picture.[image]

Each div will have its own blue box that I want to be within it via HTML but display below it via css. This blue box should only be displayed when the div is clicked, should appear beneath the div (and all others in that row but ABOVE all the divs in the next row), and should span the entire width of the parent container (so it will be the width of the 5 red divs in this picture). Is anything like this possible? I can't think of a way to really do anything like this. I've created a fiddle with a quick mock up that you can alter: https://jsfiddle.net/hL8r9fu9/

```
.wrapper {
  width:500px;
  background:white;
  height:500px;
}

.item {
  float:left;
  width: 18%;
  margin-right:2%;
  height:120px;
  background:red;
  margin-bottom:2%;
}

.info {
  height:20px;
  background:blue;
}

.info.is-hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Do the red div's wrap automatically into a second row? Or are they in a container for each row?  If they wrap automatically, then this is a semi-complex javascript problem.

Comment: could you add a pic of the result that you're expecting?

Comment: They wrap automatically. You can check out the fiddle I provided to get a general layout of my issue.

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/hL8r9fu9/2/ definitely need to tweak the js a little bit

Comment: Here is a picture of the intended result. Note that each red div has a blue div inside of it, but they all need to position the same (below that row, above the next row, push the next row down, and span the whole length of the row)

http://i63.tinypic.com/dyliit.png

Comment: Why not make 5 separate questions?

Comment: Pic doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you creating the content with a server side language? or is it all statically hard coded?

Comment: It's dynamic but it comes from the client. Try this pic instead: http://i.imgur.com/FbadAkv.png

Answer (score 0):

One way you can determine the items in a row against in another row is to use `.offset().top` on the elements ( since the value would return same for all div in the same row ).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.click(function(){
    $this.find(".info").toggleClass("is-hidden");
        if($this.offset().top > 10) // just an example value , you need to adjust this .
            $this.find(".info").css("top","0%");
    });
  });
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/hL8r9fu9/3/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the following jquery code:

```
$('.inherit-wrapper').each(function( element ) {
    var $this = $(this),
        property = $this.attr('wrapper-property'),
        value = $this.parent().parent().css(property);
    if(property && value) $this.css(property, value);
});
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/1arp3o9a/). I borrowed the function from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKHfr/) by iConner.

Answer (score 0):

I messed with your jsfiddle and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hL8r9fu9/9/) is what I got. You will have to tweak it to get what you want, but you can see where I was going with it.

html is the same and tweaked css a bit.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").click(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var info = $this.find(".info");
      var infoTopPos = $this.offset().top;
      var infoHeight = $this.height();
      var parentWidth = $this.parent().width();
      var parentLeftPos = $this.parent().offset().left;
      $(".info").not(info).addClass('is-hidden');
      $(info).toggleClass('is-hidden');
      info.css({width: parentWidth, top: (infoTopPos+infoHeight)+'px', left: parentLeftPos});
    });
});
```

Comment: @Jason Addleman this should be what you were looking for. BTW you don't need to iterate over each item.